# Is there a way that I can screen scrape the code within the "inspect element" area?

Tags: javascript, html, database, dom, screen-scraping

I'm pretty new to all of this so I hope this makes sense. So there's a difference between the data held within the source code and the inspected elements. Is there any way that I can write a program to send a get request to a specific URL and then parse through the "inspect element" code? I can't post pictures yet, so here's a link to screenshots of my problem https://i.stack.imgur.com/5U88G.jpg. In short, can I send a get request of a URL and get the inspect element code as a string?

Comment: This would more be a browser plug-in. "Inspect Element" gives you what the browser has parsed (corrected any html errors etc) and has had acted upon it by javascript etc. Therefore there is a chance that what you would get from "inspect element" would changed based on browser differences.

Answer (score 0):

Your inspect element marked area is not present in source code, may be because it is loaded dynamically. You can get data if you can figure out which API is hit by your browser to get that data. You can figure that out  using chrome's console. See in network, what APIs are hit.